# csv remove rows where second column has less than X words

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a large csv (35gb) of following format:

```
"id","text","other_info"
"1","this is some text, a news report citing more than 30 sources, including investors","some other info"
"11","this is some text","sme other info"
"111","","sme other info"
"21","this is some real text Language models with hundreds of billions of parameters","sme other info"
```

Result:

```
"id","text","other_info"
"1","this is some text, a news report citing more than 30 sources, including investors","some other info"
"21","this is some real text Language models with hundreds of billions of parameters","sme other info"
```

The problem is `text` at times has less than 10 words and I want to remove such rows.
What is a fast way to do this please?

I can write a loop in python:

```
lst=[]
for item in row:
    if len(row[1])>10:
        lst.append(row[1])
```

but this would be dead slow on my 35g file.

Comment: please update the question with sample inputs (3-5 lines, some with <10 words, some with >= 10 words), the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Comment: I have done this @markp-fuso

Comment: Can your quoted fields contain newlines, commas, or escaped quotes (`\"` or `""`)?

Comment: @EdMorton yes unfortunately they can..

Comment: please update the question to show some rows that *`contain newlines, commas, or escaped quotes`*

Comment: @markp-fuso its a 35gb file, I can tell you that it can contain those.. wouldnt that suffice?

Comment: @AJW regarding [wouldnt that suffice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77389986/csv-remove-rows-where-second-column-has-less-than-x-words?noredirect=1#comment136433304_77389986) - no, you need to provide a [mcve] we can copy/paste to test with that covers all your requirements, not just sunny-day cases, so we get a clear pass/fail from testing a potential solution against it. Otherwise you're likely to get a solution that works for the example you provided but not for your real data. Knowing your input file is 35g is only interesting in as much as it'd rule out reading it all into memory

Comment: Do you have or can you install GNU awk and, if so, which version? The latest gawk, version 5.3.0, [beta release announcement](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.awk/c/l5qjXZfOnhk) says it has CSV parsing built in with it's new `--csv` option but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this example file, test.csv:

```
1,a,other_info
2,a b,other_info
3,a b a b ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab,other_info
4,a c,other_info
5,a b a b ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab,other_info
6,a b a b ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab,other_info
```

Running `awk -F ',' '{split($2,words," "); if (length(words) >= 10) print}' test.csv` yields:

```
3,a b a b ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab,other_info
5,a b a b ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab,other_info
6,a b a b ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab,other_info
```

### UPDATE

Now, in your provided example each field is quoted, so you can leverage GNU AWK's FPAT.

`awk 'BEGIN {FPAT = "(\"[^\"]*\")"} {split($2,words," "); if (length(words) >= 10) print}' my_file.csv`

It will still use an empty string as a word separator inside the field though. So if the `text` field contains "this is some text, for example: a,b,c,d,e,f" it would consider it to have 7 words.

You can shorten this command to (all credits to @kvantour):

`awk 'BEGIN{FPAT = "(\"[^\"]*\")"} (FNR==1 || split($2,words," ") >= 10)' test.csv`

This will also print the first row (headers). The third argument to the split function is supposed to default to FS (" " by default) but in my case it didn't work until I set it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you.. since its a large file, will this still be performant? Also, will it catch if the string is empty?

Comment: 1) I have no clue on how it performs on large files, though I have heard that awk performs ok with large files. I think you will be better of trying it yourself.
2) It uses `split($2,words," ")`, so it would just split the field using an empty string. This means it will catch empty fields.

Comment: thank you - would it be better to just count chars rather than words? is there an approach to do this ?

Comment: Replacing `split($2,words," ")` with `split($2,words,"")` would make it count the chars instead of words (including opening and closing quotes). Which one to use just depends on your use case.

Comment: That won't handle newlines or escaped quotes in fields as the OP says they have in their CSV, see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

Comment: It is really tricky to correctly handle CSV in AWK. So keep that in mind when considering if this is the correct approach for your problem. It really depends on your CSV format and if you control or not it.

Comment: The answer of Ed is spot on and written down with the intent to easily understand the code. If you know that `split` returns the number of words and uses `FS`, here still `" "`, as default separator, you can awkify the code into `awk 'BEGIN{FPAT = "(\"[^\"]*\")"} (FNR==1 || split($2,words) >= 10)' file.csv`

Comment: all of these break when I test on a csv with embedded newlines

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1b;/^[^,]+,"[^" ]+(\s+[^" ]+){9}/!d' file
```

Forget the first line and then test each line for 10 or more words in the second column otherwise delete the line.

Comment: It will not delete a line with 1 word in the second and 10 words in the third column.

Comment: @WalterA oops!. See edit

Comment: this breaks when I test it on a csv with embedded newlines

Comment: @jhnc hence the second word in my solution `might`.

Answer (score 0):

(I deleted this because it wasn't very fast (perhaps 15min for your 35GB file). However since none of the sed and awk answers provided so far actually appear to work properly...)

To parse arbitrary csv, you should use a csv-aware tool.
Since you are using python:

**filtercsv:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import csv

reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

writer.writerow( next(reader) )

for row in reader:
    if row[1].count(" ") > 10:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

```
$ ./filtercsv <in.csv. >out.csv
```

I get around 36MB/s throughput on my five-year old laptop.

Answer (score -1):

> I can write a loop in python:
>
> ```
> lst=[]
> for item in row:
>     if len(row[1])>10:
>         lst.append(row[1])
> ```
>
> but this would be dead slow on my 35g file.

More serious problem is that you might run out of space for your huge `lst`. You should output to file to avoid that, I suggest following python3 solution, let `file.csv` content be

```
"id","text","other_info"
"1","this is some text, a news report citing more than 30 sources, including investors","some other info"
"11","this is some text","sme other info"
"111","","sme other info"
"21","this is some real text Language models with hundreds of billions of parameters","sme other info"
```

then

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as infile, open('file.csv', newline='') as csvfile, open('filtered.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line, row in zip(infile, reader):
        if len(row[1].split()) > 10:
            outfile.write(line)
```

creates `filtered.csv` with following content

```
"1","this is some text, a news report citing more than 30 sources, including investors","some other info"
"21","this is some real text Language models with hundreds of billions of parameters","sme other info"
```

Explanation: I open `file.csv` twice, `infile` will be used for accessing lines, `csvfile` for ramming into [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and `outfile` for writing. Then I create reader and iterate in unison over reader and file, so I have access to line as is and parsed row. If 1st element after `split`ting has more than 10 elements I write this line as-is to output file. I do not know if that solution would be fast enough for your use-case, so please test it against subset of your file and then estimate total running time. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes that more than 10 words rules apply to *all* lines of input files, including 1st one.

*(tested in Python 3.10.12)*

Comment: doesn't this assume embedded newlines cannot appear in a column?

Comment: ie. if there is not a one-one correspondence between line and row, I think they will get out of sync